# Cannot Access Website and Get Dynamic Error Messages

Tags: website, blocking

I have experienced this in the past a very few times with other websites and never understood what causes it but here is screenshot I get in when accessing http://www.kohls.com

[image]

Tried HTTPS version, tried different desktop browsers and tried Android's mobile browsers to no avail. But I can access this through proxy. In fact this website worked for me a few weeks ago.

Comment: I can get at it fine, and since you can also get at it via a proxy, then most likely your IP is blocked for some reason (that probably only Kohls knows)

Comment: Also please let us know whether it happens with all your browsers...If possible please cross check the issue with some other computer in the same LAN..

Comment: @vembutech Yes to all your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Release the ip address your isp gave you and get a new one.  As mentioned above the ip address you are using is possibly blocked.

Comment: Tried IP of free Wi-Fi hotspot around house I spotted and same thing.

Comment: Won't help if it's a blocked IP as the IP that is blocked is the one for the wan side of your ISP gateway.  That is the one you need to change.

Comment: Does not work with another ISP as well which is used in that Wi-Fi hotspot I used.